# Get name of months in which documents were created in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am building an budget app and I have spending records. Each record has `startDate` and `endDate`. Most spendings are *day* spending, like *groceries*, but some are temporary or permanent, like paying for rent.

I want to show `years` and `months` dropdown, were user chooses month and it shows spendings under that month. And I don't want to show months that don't have any spendings under it.

So, I need to query collection, so it would return months names/numbers under which there was records with `start/endDate` field.

Something like this.

```
{
    _id: 1,
    startDate: '08/10/2018',
    endDate: '09/10/2018'
}

{
    id: 2,
    startDate: '11/10/2018',
    endDate: '11/10/2018'
}
```

The result of the query should return

```
["08", "09", "11"]
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the shape of your document, the general schema? Is the array shown here the actual shape? What is the affected collection size of the query? Are you querying millions of records or a few? Who is accessing this query and how often? {many, some, a few} users {many, some, a few} times? Where is the code running? Something load-balanced like a serverless architecture or a standalone server with limited memory? Is this maybe some one-off analytics task where performance isn't relevant?

Comment: The shape is as above, with _id, startDate, andDate and bunch of other fields. It's not millions records, probably thousands. All users will access this query when they are opening their spending page. The code will run in AWS

Comment: Thousands in total or thousands per user? Can you just do this calculation in-memory?

Comment: Also AWS has many services, do you know on which one is this running? Basically i'm exploring if you can do this calculation in-memory

Comment: it will be better if `startDate` and `endDate` is `Date` type :P

Comment: Its thousands per user. I am not sure about the service yet. You mean by memory is get all records and get months using js ?

Comment: @user2960708 yes.

Comment: startDate and endDate are Date type. I wrote it as a string for simplicity.

Comment: Bad idea. It is a hell lot of difference between a string and a Date